# Laravel: Find specific object from has many relation

Tags: laravel

Just curious if there is a easy way to do this. Example

```
$post = Post::find(1);
$post->comments()->get(); //will return all comments associated to post.
```

Is there a way to pass a id to the comments call to retrive a specific comment?

EG

```
$post->comments(1)->get();
```

Thoughts.

Comment: `$post->comments()` is a Relation object, which behaves pretty much the same as any Model. That being said you can query it just like your models: `$post->comments()->where(...)->orderBy(...)->get()` or in your case `$post->comments()->find($id);`

Comment: Thanks @deczo !, that did the trick. Still wrapping my head around all the Laravel awesomeness.

Answer (score 0):

If the relation is HasMany you can do this:

```
$post = Comment::where('post_id','=',1)->post;
```

or

```
$post = Post::comments()->where('id','=',1)->first();
```